# Handling data in response from Facebook graph API

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to handle Facebook advertising data recieved via a batched request.

```
$requests = [
        $fb->request("GET", "act_XXXX/insights/?fields=account_id,spend,campaign_id,campaign_name&level=campaign&date_preset=last_30_days"),
        $fb->request("GET", "act_XXXX/insights/?fields=account_id,adset_name,adset_id,spend&level=adset&date_preset=last_30_days"),
        $fb->request("GET", "act_XXXX/insights/?fields=account_id,adset_name,campaign_name,ad_name,spend&level=ad&date_preset=last_30_days"),
    ];
```

This works as intended and the result I get back with `$res = $response->getBody();` is like ( with `var_dump($res);` ):

```
string '{"data":[{"account_id":"895282637172047",.....
string '{"data":[{"account_id":"895282637172047",.....
string '{"data":[{"account_id":"895282637172047",.....
```

All with different data based on campaign, adset or ad.

Here my problem arrises, because I want handle the 3 different JSON's differently.

So my question is how I can differentiate them so I can do something like

```
foreach($data1 as $datas) {

}

foreach($data2 as $datas) {

}

foreach($data3 as $datas) {

}
```

Comment: have you considered using the PHP SDK for the Ads API? It handles all of this magic for you:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk

Comment: I have tried to test it with PHP SDK - but can it be true that I have to "foreach" loop through the campaign list and again through the adset list? 

That will generate a lot of calls. 

With the graph API I can get all insights data with one call.

Comment: Bah... Missed the level parameter

Comment: @PaulBain 
Can you give an answer? I tried again with the PHP SDK and it works perfectly!

Comment: can you be clearer what you're trying to achieve?